# Using Sum With Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, ssms

How can I get the Sum of data from a secondary table w/o using a join?

```
Select emp.ID, emp.fname, emp.lname, emp.address1, 
emp.address2, emp.city, emp.state, emp.zip, emp.phone, 
Sales = SUM(Select sales from empPerformance where saledate between @startdate And @enddate)
From employeeData emp
Group By emp.Id, emp.fname, emp.lname, 
emp.address1, emp.address2, emp.city, 
emp.state, emp.zip, emp.phone
```

and this gives me the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: `sales = (SELECT SUM(sales) FROM empPerformance AS ep WHERE emp.ID = ep.emp_id AND saledate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)`

Comment: that gives the same Sales value for all employees, not the specific sales amount for the user for that row

Comment: Do you realize that your inner query will sum the sales for all employees because you don't link `emp_id`?

Comment: *that gives the same Sales value for all employees* Look carefully. Especially on **emp.ID = ep.emp_id**.

Comment: Akina's query should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also group it in inner query.

```
SELECT emp.ID, emp.fname, emp.lname, emp.address1 
    , emp.address2, emp.city, emp.state, emp.zip, emp.phone, s.Sales
FROM (
    SELECT emp_id, SUM(sales) AS Sales
    FROM empPerformance
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    GROUP BY emp_id
) s
JOIN employeeData emp ON emp.Id = s.emp_id
```